# What is the name of this construction for a compound policy that operates over distinct action sets?

Tags: reinforcement-learning, deep-rl, terminology, math, policies

I am developing an RL algorithm with a policy that needs to compute valid probabilities over multiple distinct action sets. I think I have a construction that will work, but I do not know what it is called, or if it even has a name:

Given two discrete policies $\pi_{A_1}: A_1 \times S \rightarrow [0, 1]$ and $\pi_{A_2}: A_2 \times S \rightarrow [0, 1]$, there is a policy $\pi_{A_1 \cup A_1}: (A_1 \cup A_2) \times S \rightarrow [0, 1]$ defined:

$$
\begin{align*}
\pi_{A_1 \cup A_2}(x \mid s) = 
\left\{
    \begin{array}{lr}
        m_{1} \cdot \pi_{A_1}(x \mid s) & x \in A_1 \\
        m_{2} \cdot \pi_{A_2}(x \mid s) & x \in A_2
    \end{array}
\right\}
\end{align*}
$$

where $m_{1} + m_{2} = 1$, $m_{i} \geq 0$, and $A_1 \cap A_2 = \emptyset$.

The proof that this is a valid policy is simple:

$$
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\sum_{x \in A_1 \cup A_2} \pi_{A_1 \cup A_2}(x \mid s) &= \sum_{a_1 \in A} m_{1} \cdot \pi_{A_1}(a_1 \mid s) + \sum_{a_2 \in A_2} m_{2} \cdot \pi_{A_2}(a_2 \mid s) \\
&= m_{1} \cdot \sum_{a_1 \in A_1} \pi_{A_1}(a_1 \mid s) + m_{2} \cdot \sum_{a_2 \in A_2} \pi_{A_2}(a_2 \mid s) \\ 
&= m_{1} + m_{2} \\
&= 1
\end{split}
\end{equation}
$$

It doesn't look like a mixture policy due to the splitting behavior. Again, I'm curious if this has a name, or what other constructions to which it might be related.